# How to have region as variable when using DefaultStackSynthesizer in CDK

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a CDK project and for a specific reason, I need to be able to deploy the CFN template generated using `cdk synth` in any region in any AWS region so the generated templates needs to have the region as variable.

Basically in the generated template I need to have something like this:

```json
    "S3Bucket": {"Fn::Sub": "mybucket-for-assets-${AWS::Region}" },
```

I tried to used DefaultStackSynthesizer to customize it so with the following code

```js
    synthesizer: new DefaultStackSynthesizer({
            fileAssetsBucketName: "cdk-assets-${AWS::Region}",
            bucketPrefix: '',
          })
```

It generates something like this

```json
    "S3Bucket": "mybucket-for-assets-eu-west-1"
```

Is it possible to achieve that by customising even more the Synthesizer ?

LATER EDIT: my issue is with the bucket that holds the assets. I need to use a custom bucket and the name to contains the region (as variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
synthesizer: new DefaultStackSynthesizer({
        fileAssetsBucketName: `cdk-assets-${Aws.REGION}`,
        bucketPrefix: '',
      })
```

This should result in CFN Template, which injects the region when deploying.

Comment: It works. Actually with " instead of `but it seems to work. I noticed that in the CFN template I have ${Aws.REGION} instead of ${AWS::Region}. Is the same?

Comment: The output should be a a CFN join function, sth like this: ```{
  "Fn::Join": [
    "", [
      "bucket-name-",
      {
        "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
      }
    ]
  ]
}```

Comment: So the code as it is does not works, it complains about the ` symbol. When I put double quotes, it generates something like "S3Bucket": {
      "Fn::Sub": "my-cdk-assets-bucket-${Aws.REGION}"
     }

Comment: This is the error when using `symbol  -> 'fileAssetsBucketName' cannot contain tokens; only the following placeholder strings are allowed: ${Qualifier}, ${AWS::Region}, ${AWS::AccountId}, ${AWS::Partition}

Comment: Ah, so they got there a custom implementation. So if the double quotes method works then just use it :)